# Solving an inverting opamp with stability compensation

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I am trying to calculate the transfer function of this circuit with a non-ideal opamp (Vopamp = -A*V-), but I don't have enough equations to solve it... I found 4 individual loops for 2 nodes (I output opamp is not useful, and I think I can still consider the bias current to be zero, but I am not sure?) so 6+1=7 equations, but I think there are 9 unknowns: Vi, Vo, V-, Vk (output of opamp), Ii, If, Ic, Io, Il.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG29OP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This circuit can be solved in many ways but I will use the Extra-Element Theorem or EET described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem) but also [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371) with the Fast Analytical Techniques. The principle consists of identifying an element that bothers you in the calculation of the transfer function - the extra element - and you calculate a reference gain \$G_{ref}\$ when this element is either set to 0 or open-circuited. I choose to remove \$R_f\$ for the first gain calculation. The schematic is below:

[image]

The gain in this configuration has been determined in the second link and is equal to:

\$G_{ref}=-\frac{R_c}{R_i}\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{R_c}{R_i}+1}{A_{OL}}+1}\frac{R_L}{R_L+R_o}\approx -\frac{R_c}{R_i}\frac{R_L}{R_L+R_o}\$

Ok, we have our reference gain. Now, let's calculate the resistance \$R_d\$ "seen" from \$R_f\$'s terminals when the excitation \$V_{in}\$ is set to 0 V (replaced by a sort circuit). The circuit is below:

[image]

If you do the maths correctly, you should find:

\$R_d=\frac{R_cR_i(R_L+R_o+A_{OL}R_L)}{(R_L+R_o)(R_c+R_i+A_{OL}R_i)}+R_L||R_o\approx \frac{R_cR_iR_L}{(R_L+R_o)R_i}+R_L||R_o\$

For the final lap, we need to determine the resistance \$R_n\$ "seen" from \$R_f\$'s terminals when the response \$V_{out}\$ is a null or equal to 0 V when the excitation is back. Let's see the below schematic:

[image]

Solving this circuit is easy (I used a Thévenin circuit) and you should find a resistance equal to: \$R_n=-\frac{(R_L||R_o)(R_L+R_o)}{A_{OL}R_L}\approx 0 \;\Omega\$

We can now apply the EET formula defined as:

\$G=G_{ref}\frac{1+\frac{R_n}{R_f}}{1+\frac{R_d}{R_f}}\$ which gives (considering an infinite open-loop gain):

\$G=-\frac{R_cR_L}{R_i(R_L+R_o)}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\frac{R_cR_iR_L}{(R_L+R_o)R_i}+R_L||R_o}{R_f}}\$

If you bias this circuit input with a 1-V dc source, the output is calculated to -0.884 V, confirmed by the below simulation:

[image]

The Mathcad file below confirms this number:

[image]

If you now replace \$R_L\$ by a capacitor impedance, you can plot the frequency response of the circuit:

[image]

**New Edit:**

I realize that the above formula was correct however, when \$Z_L\$ is a capacitor, it is clearly a high-entropy expression. It is better to select \$Z_L\$ as a capacitor as all the other elements will be resistors. As such, the above formula does not tell you where the pole is located when you load the circuit with a capacitor. To derive a low-entropy formula, we will first determine the dc gain when \$Z_L\$ is removed. The circuit is shown below:

[image]

The gain in this mode for a perfect op amp is: \$G_0=-\frac{R_cR_f}{R_cR_i+R_fR_i+R_iR_o}\$

Now, install a test current source \$I_T\$ across \$Z_L\$'s terminals and determine the resistance "seen" from these terminals. The sketch is below:

[image]

The resistance is: \$R_d=\frac{R_fR_iR_o}{R_cR_i+R_fR_i+R_iR_o}\$
The time constant is equal to: \$\tau_1=C_1\frac{R_fR_iR_o}{R_cR_i+R_fR_i+R_iR_o}\$

The final transfer function is thus: \$G(s)=G_0\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$ with \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{\tau_1}\$.

The below Mathcad files confirm these results which match the ones previously found. In the latest case however, you can express the pole position in a clear manner.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Knowing all the currents is fine, or knowing all the voltages is fine. Either fully define the behavior and are computable from the other.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm the one missing something, but two of your unknowns, Vo and Vi need not to be solved beforehand.

Vo should be expressed as a function of Vi, so once you solve all the other unknowns you'd have Vo(Vi) = Vi * CONST_EXPR

You test for some Vi (say, a particular sine signal) and get a Vo